# How to catch NoSuchLayoutException in Liferay Velocity theme when layout not found?

Tags: exception, liferay, velocity, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I have the following code in a velocity template theme:

```
#set($currLayout = $layoutLocalService.getFriendlyURLLayout($group_id, true, $currFriendlyUrl))
```

which throws a

```
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchLayoutException
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.getFriendlyURLLayout(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:959)
```

when matching layout not exist.

How could I catch this exception in my velocity template?

Comment: In Liferay you can rely on the fetch*() method, as it doesn't throw Exceptions and returns null if no result was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to catch exceptions inside a velocity template. Generally, there are two ways of dealing with such a situation:

- handle the exception in the application which uses the template, such as a servlet
- avoid throwing exceptions; instead, have the method always return a valid (default) value, or `null` if that is not possible

The [velocity manual](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/creatingtools.html#Designing_Template-Friendly_Interfaces) recommends to use the second option whenever possible.

Comment: You are right. After some research I found out it is not possible to catch exceptions inside a velocity template.
On the other hand, the method I posted "$layoutLocalService.getFriendlyURLLayout" is a Liferay's method where I do not have control over its behavior, and what it does is throwing an exception if layout does not exist.

So a solution would be to try to override somehow this method or create a hook overriding some servlet in liferay.

The other approach, which I finally followed, was to try to ensure that all layouts exist, putting this code in conditional statements.

Comment: I just wondered whether a more straight-forward safe approach for such cases existed.

Thanks a lot for your answer anyhow!

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me, but I am not familiar with Liferay. Maybe it is possible to define a default layout?

Comment: Sounds a good idea in general, thank you. That could be another question for the liferay people, whether it is possible to set a default layout. Although from the liferay API it does not seem to be supported out of the box.
http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portal/service/LayoutLocalService.html#getFriendlyURLLayout%28long,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String%29